# How do I install Ubuntu without making a CD or flash drive?

Tags: windows-7

I am currently running Windows 7 on my laptop. I want to install Ubuntu with windows 7. I have downloaded the Windows installer of Ubuntu. Can I install Ubuntu without making a bootable CD or flash drive of Ubuntu?

Comment: It is downloaded as .rar file.

Comment: If you are downloading a .rar file, you are not downloading an official Ubuntu distribution.

Answer (score 6):

Windows installer for ubuntu can be downloaded from http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/windows-installer and what you get is wubi.exe. Else, if you downloaded an ISO image, you can follow Javier's solution to extract wubi.exe. But I never saw a .rar  as Ubuntu installer. (I may be wrong as well). Anyway, please confirm if it is really an ubuntu installer.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Ubuntu inside a virtual machine like virtualbox and using daemon tools to directly mount the image if you don't want to burn a cd.

Answer (score 1):

Use some windows tool to mount the image (like Deamon Tools) and run [wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/windows-installer), just double click on wubi.exe. This is not exactly a *normal* installation but it's close enough for most purposes.

Comment: I disagree, it is a real installation albeit on a large file inside Windows. Phoronix tests in the past have found it faster in certain applications!

Comment: I know that is real in a strict sense. But it's quite different in a couple of situations to standard Ubuntu installs. I'll seek for a better wording.

Comment: @JavierRivera I have windows 10 and did not get `wubi`. All I got is a disk image. How can I install ubuntu from that ISO file (btw, I mounted the drive and searched `wubi.exe` but could not find it)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are talking about wubi. Run the installer, and wait until it downloads the iso image. If you already have the iso image put it in the same folder with the installer and run the installer. You don't need a bootable cd.

Answer (score 0):

Just mount the iso file and then open the iso file with winrar and then click wubi and install. then the installer itself pick the files from the mounted drive.

Comment: The asker says he already has WUBI.